# Find dates inside range when date is stored as year, month and day separately

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, datetime

I have a table which has columns Year, Month, Day, which are INT, and have some other columns. The size of the table is very huge.

Now, I want to retrieve the data within the date range, say between @StartDate and @EndDate.

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable
WHERE 10000*M.[YEAR]+100*M.[Month]+M.[Day] >= 10000*YEAR(@StartDate)+100*MONTH(@StartDate)+DAY(@StartDate) 
    AND 10000*M.[YEAR]+100*M.[Month]+M.[Day] < 10000*YEAR(@EndDate)+100*MONTH(@EndDate)+DAY(@EndDate)
```

This makes the SQL Server scan the index, not seek index.

Is there a way to make it as Index Seek? I mean how to change the logic here?

I'm using SQL Server, but I guess it applies to other database too.

Comment: What index(es) do you have on the table?

Comment: a non-cluster index which includes year,month,day. maybe should have an index for each?

Comment: Your index will not help when you perform calculations on the columns. Without changing your schema the only thing I can think of is to break up your StartDate and EndDate into year, month, day and compare them with your date columns using a combination of AND, OR conditions in the WHERE clause. e.g. WHERE year >= 2017 AND year < 2018 AND month >= ... OR ...

Comment: You can reconstruct the date with DATEFROMPARTS but the query will  still be slow. You can't use any index when the date value has to be computed for each row. Add a calculated field with a `date` type that returns `DATEFROMPARTS(Year, Month, Day)`  and add it to an index

Comment: which version of sqlserver are you using and what value `StartDate` is holding i mean `date` or `datetime` ?

Comment: The proper solution is to store dates as dates, not as three integers.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in using [DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable M
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(M.[Year], M.[Month], M.[Day]) between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

**Edit**
Based on the comment, I recommend creating a date persisted calculated field that will combine the Year and Month and Day

Hope this will help you

Comment: THis will allow the query to run but performance will be bad. The server will have to scan the entire table to constuct the date value

Comment: I believe the best practice is to create a persisted a calculated field

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would do it:

```
DECLARE @Start date = '2016-01-23'
DECLARE @End date = '2017-04-22';



SELECT * FROM DataTable DT
JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(@Start) SY
        , MONTH(@Start) SM
        , DAY(@Start) SD
        , YEAR(@End) EY
        , MONTH(@End) EM
        , DAY(@End) ED
        ) MMM
    ON ( 
        MMM.SY < DT.YEAR
        OR ( MMM.SY = DT.YEAR AND 
             ( MMM.SM < DT.MONTH OR
                ( MMM.SM = DT.MONTH AND MMM.SD <= DT.DAY )
             )
            )
        )
        AND 
        ( 
        MMM.EY > DT.YEAR
        OR ( MMM.EY = DT.YEAR AND 
             ( MMM.EM > DT.MONTH OR
                ( MMM.EM = DT.MONTH AND MMM.ED >= DT.DAY )
             )
            )
        )

    ;
```

Comment: this still uses index scan, not index seek.

Comment: Hmmm.. then don't you need to look at the index structure to design index(es) that would be able support a seek in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me how do i populate my table with dummy data ?

Don't use *,instead mention all require column along with their data type
so that it give fair idea whent creating index

If you answer my above question then I update my answer accordingly.

Try this,

```
    DECLARE @Start date = '2000-01-23'
    DECLARE @End date = '2017-04-22';

   CREATE table MainTable(yr int not null,mnth int not null,d int not null)
create nonclustered index #MainTable_ymd on MainTable(yr ,mnth ,d )
----create nonclustered index #MainTable_y on #MainTable(yr)include(mnth ,d ) 
----here include(other column) so that it is covering index
----truncate table MainTable

insert into MainTable WITH(tablock)
select year(dt),month(dt),day(dt)
from
(
select top (10000000) dateadd(day,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by a.number)/5,'1900-01-01')dt from master..spt_values a 
,master..spt_values  b
)t4

I populate maintable with dummy data with 63,25,225 rows

   --Solution 1

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT yr
        ,mnth
        ,d
        ,cast(cast(yr AS VARCHAR(4)) + right('00' + cast(mnth AS VARCHAR), 2) + right('00' + cast(d AS VARCHAR), 2) AS DATE) dt
    FROM MainTable
    WHERE yr >= year(@Start)
        AND yr <= year(@End)
    ) t4
WHERE dt >= @Start
    AND dt <= @End


--RETURN
-- Solution 2
-- here put the result in temp table

CREATE table #tmp1(yr int,mnth int,d int,dt date not null)

INSERT INTO #tmp1
SELECT yr
    ,mnth
    ,d
    ,cast(cast(yr AS VARCHAR(4)) + right('00' + cast(mnth AS VARCHAR), 2) + right('00' + cast(d AS VARCHAR), 2) AS DATE) dt
FROM MainTable
WHERE yr >= year(@Start)
    AND yr <= year(@End)


create clustered index #tmp1dt on #tmp1(dt)

select * from #tmp1
where dt>=@Start and dt<=@End

--drop table MainTable

drop table #tmp1
```

I am getting Index seek in both solution.

With JOhnRC query I get table scan and parallelism ,with urlreader also i get table scan using same sample data.

@Monah query-- TableScan

Comment: "Copy all the data to another table" isn't a very practical solution. Definitely not when you end up copying a year's data simply to search for a single week

Comment: MainTable  is my own dummy data,it has nothing to do with main query.in solution 2,i am inserting to temp table,sometime putting intermediate result to temp table help.What about solution 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Can** we try in this way:

```
select *
from dateCompare
where concat(Eyear, Emonth, Eday) between replace(@startDate, '-', '') 
                                      and replace(@endDate, '-', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select * from DataTable M
where 
(   M.[YEAR] > YEAR(@StartDate)
    OR (M.[YEAR] = YEAR(@StartDate)
        AND M.[Month] > Month(@StartDate) )
    OR (M.[YEAR] = YEAR(@StartDate)
        AND M.[Month] = Month(@StartDate)
        AND M.[Day]  >= Day(@StartDate) )
)
AND 
(   M.[YEAR] < YEAR(@EndDate)
    OR (M.[YEAR] = YEAR(@EndDate)
        AND M.[Month] < Month(@EndDate) )
    OR (M.[YEAR] = YEAR(@StartDate)
        AND M.[Month] = Month(@EndDate)
        AND M.[Day]  < Day(@EndDate)    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer which definitely uses index seek on DataTable (assuming the index is (YEAR, MONTH, DAY) when using SQL SERVER 2014.  However, I suspect this might take longer than the simpler approach unless the selected date range is quite narrow. I would be interested to know how it performs on the real data.

The approach is to create a table of all possible dates between the start and end date, then join this table to the DataTable on exact match of YEAR, MONTH and DAY.

```
-- Paramters setting date range
DECLARE @Start date = '2016-01-23'
DECLARE @End date = '2017-04-22';

-- Create a table of all dates between start and end dates
CREATE TABLE #DATES 
(
    YY int
    , MM int
    , DD int
);

-- There are better ways to do this but for the sake of simplicity...
WHILE @Start <= @End
begin
 INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ( YEAR(@Start), MONTH(@Start), DAY(@Start) );
 SET @Start = Dateadd(Day,1, @Start);
end ;

-- Finally, join the DataTable to the created dates with exact match
SELECT DT.* 
    FROM DataTable DT
        JOIN #DATES DD
        ON DD.YY = DT.YEAR
        AND DD.MM = DT.MONTH
        AND DD.DD = DT.DAY;

-- Finished with the dates table
DROP TABLE #DATES;
```

Comment: A variation of this is to create a table containing _all_ dates (say between 1990 and 2050) stored as `(Date, Y, M, D)` and join with that table.

Comment: @SalmanA - Strangely, when I tried this using a join against the dates table, selecting dates within the date range, the execution plan reverted to using an Index Scan on the DataTable. Not sure why that should be.